# Espresso: how to scroll to the bottom of ScrollView

Tags: android, android-espresso

How is it possible to scroll down to the bottom of ScrollView in Espresso test? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 51, accepted):

If at the bottom of the ScrollView you need to find a view and match something against it, then simply perform the `scrollTo()` action on it, before any other actions that require it to be displayed.

```
onView(withId(R.id.onBottomOfScrollView))
    .perform(scrollTo(), click());
```

> Note: scrollTo will have no effect if the view is already displayed so you can safely use it in cases when the view is displayed

Comment: I haven't tried that, but give it a shot and write a new question with the issue

Comment: works only if you know your child elements - what to do if you dont know the last element?

Comment: `perform(swipeDown())`, that saved my day!

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Take a look at https://medium.com/@devasierra/espresso-nestedscrollview-scrolling-via-kotlin-delegation-5e7f0aa64c09

Answer (score 21):

for me when using nestedScrollview i just swipeUp (if you want to go down)..here is an example call:

```
onView(withId(R.id.nsv_container))
                .perform(swipeUp());
```

Answer (score 13):

For completeness (based on Morozov's answer), you can pass a custom `ViewAction` instead of `scrollTo()`, which allows to use `NestedScrollView`:

```
ViewAction customScrollTo = new ViewAction() {

    @Override
    public Matcher<View> getConstraints() {
        return allOf(withEffectiveVisibility(ViewMatchers.Visibility.VISIBLE), isDescendantOfA(anyOf(
            isAssignableFrom(ScrollView.class),
            isAssignableFrom(HorizontalScrollView.class),
            isAssignableFrom(NestedScrollView.class)))
        );
    }

    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void perform(UiController uiController, View view) {
        new ScrollToAction().perform(uiController, view);
    }
};
```

And use it like this:

```
onView(withId(R.id.onBottomOfScrollView)).perform(customScrollTo, click());
```

Answer (score 1):

Also u can try:

```
public Matcher<View> getConstraints() {
return allOf(withEffectiveVisibility(ViewMatchers.Visibility.VISIBLE), isDescendantOfA(anyOf(
        isAssignableFrom(ScrollView.class), isAssignableFrom(HorizontalScrollView.class), isAssignableFrom(NestedScrollView.class))));
```

If you have a view inside android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView instead of scrollView scrollTo() does not work.

Comment: Where do I put/call this method?

Comment: I believe this answer is missing information for whoever is not fully aware. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35272953/espresso-scrolling-not-working-when-nestedscrollview-or-recyclerview-is-in-coor for the full answer